# Send data packet over TCP using PHP socket

Tags: php, sockets, tcp, binary, hex

I want to send a command to a third party server over TCP protocol, in their documentation they listed the following command data format:

| Syntax | Bytes | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| card_id | 4 | 0x12345678 |
| param1 | 2 | 0 |
| param2 | 1 | 1 |
| param3 | 1 | 0 |
| time | 4 | time_t corresponding to 2004-6-1 13:00:00 |
| data_len | 1 | 08 |
| data_body | Variable (determinedby data_len) | "12345678" |

I want to use socket_write function in php to send the packet, so my question is how can I convert these values to send it?

Firstly: I convert each value to hexadecimal then I put it together into one string variable (each byte represent 2 hex characters). For example: 1 will be 01 if value is on 1 byte / 1 will be 0001 if value is on 2 bytes

Secondly: I convert each value to binary(01) then I put it together into one string variable (each byte represent 8 bit). For example: 1 will be 00000001 if value is on 1 byte / 1 will be 00000000 000000001 if value is on 2 bytes

Please can anyone help me to know how can I represent the command data to send over tcp socket in php ? I am a bit confused.

Comment: Use the [`pack()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) function.

Comment: How can I use it I have multiple types integer, hex and string data. Can you give me an example please.

Comment: I posted an answer, but it seems like you didn't even read the documentation, since it explains how to do that.

Comment: I read it before but I didn't understand how to use it in my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`pack()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) function to encode a number of values as bytes of a string.

```
$packet = pack('NnCCNCa*', $card_id, $param1, $param2, $param3, $time, $data, $data);
```

- `N` = unsigned 4-byte number
- `n` = unsigned 2-byte number
- `C` = unsigned byte
- `a*` = string

The 4-byte and 2-byte formats are big-endian, which corresponds to network byte order.

Comment: Should I use 'N' or 'H' for hex (card id) ?

Comment: N. You're not really sending hex, it's just showing the sample value that way.

Comment: Thank you for help, Now I am sending data using socket_write() and when I am trying to read data using [socket_read()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-read.php) it returns the following message: socket_read(): unable to read from socket [10054]: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.